# Msahci.sys is Corrupt (Windows 7 64 Bit SSD)

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd, bios

My computer did not restart correctly recently and afterwards it stopped being able to boot.

The error on the system diagnostic says `msahci.sys` is corrupt.

Currently, I can only access restore tools and the command line.

Where can I find a replacement of this .sys file? (It's only 32kbs.)

How can I replace it using CMD prompt after I have it on a USB stick?

Comment: You should be able to use SFC within the WinRE environment to solve this problem.  All the files required to repair any corrupt files within your windows image is located within the .wim located within the WinRE you have access too.  Tons of documentation on how to do this.

Comment: That is awesome! I notice SFC has several options, which is recommended for this fix?

Comment: .....The option that will repair an offline Window installation